# mobile app testing in watir

Tags: automation, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver, ios-ui-automation

I have been trying to locate WATIR/Webdriver gem for automating mobile applications. So far I am successful in finding the resources for Mobile Website testing but could not find Mobile Application automation testing like seeTest (experitest.com) provides. Like for example, i have an iPhone and it has tic-tac-toe app installed on it. I want to automate it through Watir/Webdriver or any other gem available to launch app from iphone and start playing it.

Can we accomplish such use case in watir?

Answer (score 3):

Watir (and Selenium) can automate browsers only (including browsers on mobile devices). If you need to automate native mobile applications, take a look at [appium](https://github.com/appium/appium), [calabash](https://github.com/calabash), [Frank](https://github.com/moredip/Frank) or [robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/).

Comment: can we integrate it with watir-webdriver or ruby

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate"?

Comment: Can I use this library in my ruby code like I use watir-webdriver or any other gem?

Comment: Did you even take a look if the tools are written in Ruby or not? That would answer your question, right?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, still doesn't look like there's support for watir in Appium. It's good for selenium though, just the drawbacks are that you can't use the page object gem.